# Printf(" ABCD" ); printf("ABCD" +1);

Tags: c

```
void main()

{

printf("ABCD");

   printf("\n");

   printf("ABCD" +1);

   printf("\n");

   printf("ABCD" +3);

}
```

Outputs is:

```
ABCD

BCD

D
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: On my system this prints out ABCD, then just plain D.  Are you sure you have the output as BCD for "ABCD" + 3?

Comment: @pgm I don't like it aight but you should actually exit with an syscall exit(0); so you can actually use void main() and still return a usable exit value ;)

Comment: @Dip: the point is that `void main` is only valid in freestanding implementations (microwave ovens, ABS systems, air conditioning systems, ...). Compilers for hosted implementations (anything with an Operating System) are free to format your hard disk when presented with a source file containing `void main`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`"ABCD"` is actually an array of characters `{'A','B','C','D', '\0'}` (where `'\0'` is the trailing null byte).  If you add 3 to that, then that is the equivalent of advancing a pointer 3 bytes forward from A, so you end up pointing at `D`.

Question [6.2 in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) has a picture that makes this clearer.  The array decays to a pointer as described in [6.4](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) so you have the situation of the variable `p`.

```
char a[] = "hello";
char *p = "world";
```

[image: Picture from C FAQ]

Comment: @pmg does my change in wording make it clearer?  What would you suggest?  I'm not sure what you mean by "decays to a pointer"

Comment: I thought the Standard used the term "decay". Turns out it doesn't. Arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements in most contexts: see 6.3.2.1/3 in [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

`"ABCD"` is treated as a pointer to a block of memory containing four characters followed by a null terminator (`\0`).

`"ABCD" + 1` adds `1` to the pointer, causing it to point one byte further.